# kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker issue

Tags: iphone, audio-recording, speaker

i need to trigger the iphone audio route back and forth from speaker to normal mode very quickly. I've created an audio Session similar to this site:

http://atastypixel.com/blog/using-remoteio-audio-unit/

Im creating a app that can do VOIP.

So let me explain the simple issue i have.  I have a button that toggles from speaker to normal mode like this:

```
if(speakerState){
        value = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_None;
        error = AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute, sizeof(value), &value);
        speakerState = false;
}
else {
        value = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker;
        error = AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute, sizeof(value), &value);
        speakerState = true;
}
```

... you get the idea just toggling the speaker on and off.

Here is the issue:  When the end user RAPIDLY hits the button to toggle the speaker after about 10 presses the application freezes for a while as if its releasing something and after 30 seconds comes back.  I need the end user to be able to constantly tap this button on/off as much as they want.

update:  I tried calling the speakers in the background thread but still if i press the speakers too many times it freezes or i loose audio here is the code:

-(void) manageSpeakerState{

```
OSStatus error;
UInt32 value;

if(speakerState){
    value = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_None;
    error = AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute, sizeof(value), &value);

    speakerBtn.selected = false;
    speakerState = false;
}
else {

    value = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker;
    error = AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute, sizeof(value), &value);

    speakerBtn.selected = true;
    speakerState = true;
}
```

}

// this gets called whenever the speaker button is pressed ..it toggles the speakers on/off
-(IBAction) speaker
{

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(manageSpeakerState) withObject:nil ]; 


}
```

**UPDATE: My audio session is running on a seperate thread using pthread and its in a .c file.  It could be a concurrency issue as it seems when the main thread gets tied up this issue occurs.  How can i update the audio route on the thread that the audio session is running on ?**

UPDATE: i have the same issue as this:    http://lists.apple.com/archives/coreaudio-api/2012/Jul/msg00129.html

Whenever i change routes (ie. speaker or headphone) my audioUnits are paused so im reading empty stuff into the buffers.  Its almost like a hardware manufacturer issue.  How can i get around this ? the call backs are still being called but theres no audio unit while switching routes.

Answer (score 0):

On button click just change button's background image and tag.Change audio session property in background thread.

Answer (score 0):

In your application delegate just add this piece of code..I hope it work fine.

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier newTaskId = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
newTaskId = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:NULL];
```

Comment: im not sure what your hinting at, i tried this but it did not help. im having the same issue as this user:  http://lists.apple.com/archives/coreaudio-api/2012/Jul/msg00129.html